# update table while preserving the value of a column

Tags: php, oracle, csv

I have a scheduled job that will parse the following CSV file, and if the server is already in the table execute an update, insert if not. (The server name is the key).

The problem is that the CSV may contain lines with the same server but with a different application. In those cases, I must do an update, but keep the previous value of the app.

How can I keep the previous value before updating?

```
server_name;ip_address;domain;application
s1;10.10.10.4;dom1;app1
s1;10.10.10.4;dom1;app2
s2;10.15.69.8;dom5;app10
s3;10.15.69.39;dom7;app5
```

My code is like (`$tab` contains what I have on the table)

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($lines))!== false){
   if (in_array($line[0],$tab)){ //update query}
   else { //insert query }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand your dilemma if you included starting data for both the file and the table, and showed the desired outcome for all three cases (new server name, existing server name + existing app name, existing server name + new app name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say this is a scheduled job. Because this is a repeating activity it would be worth your while to build some infrastructure: specifically an external table to provide a SQL interface for the CSV file.

External tables are highly neat: they are defined using CREATE TABLE but instead of a storage clause we specify a source file (pretty similar to SQL*Loader controlfile syntax). Then we can query the data in the CSV file without loading it into a staging table. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E.htm#SUTIL011).

As for the problem of inserting and updating you should check out the MERGE statement. This handles INSERT and UPDATE in a single statement. Note that you can drive the MERGE using an external table:

```
merge into your_table
    using ( select * from external_table ) ext
    on ( your_table.server_name = ext.server_name )
when not matched 
     then insert values ( ext.server_name, ....)
when matched 
     then update set your_table.ip_address = ext.ip_address ....
```

We can apply conditional filters to the INSERT and UPDATE clauses. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the External tables tip. I'm probably using it as soon as I have some spare time. now being in a rush I just created a specific loop where I create an array with the concatenated values : `array ([s1] => app1, app2 [s2] => app10 [s3] => app5)` then run my update.

Answer (score 0):

Import you csv rows value in a temporary parking table  and then use an insert select for the rows not in your final destination table

```
insert into your_final_dest (server_name,ip_address,domain,application)
select server_name,ip_address,domain,application
from your_csv_parking 
where server_name not  in ( select server_name from your_final_dest )
```

adn use update for others

```
UPDATE your_final_dest 
SET application  = (SELECT application
                    FROM your_csv_parking 
                    WHERE your_final_dest.server = your_csv_parking.server)
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT your_csv_parking.application
                FROM your_csv_parking 
                WHERE your_final_dest.server = your_csv_parking.server);
```